# in retool how to connect and upload the data in firebase using retool

Tags: firebase, retool

in retool how to connect and upload the data in firebase using retool ,if any one help me out.

```
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC0W4G9vFxKV99kYDPvw_qgoMOF6Yj720g",
    authDomain: "test-b0e28.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://test-b0e28-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "test-b0e28",
    storageBucket: "test-b0e28.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "729064532529",
    appId: "1:729064532529:web:ab1263c616218ebb990310",
    measurementId: "G-Y64XEPGK2V"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

Comment: if any one know retool firebase .plz help m out

Answer (score 0):

Retool has a [native integration with Firebase](https://retool.com/integrations/firebase), so you use their GUI for querying instead of writing in the SDK directly. Here's an example of what it looks like to query Firestore:

[image]

To connect a data source, you go to `yoursubdomain.retool.com/resources/new` and then find Firebase.